# SOAP over JMS for starters

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, jms, cxf

We have a web service which has been running on SOAP over HTTP using Apache CXF, and needs to be switched to SOAP over JMS. This is relatively new grounds for me and the internet didn't seem to give all the answers for me, or i couldn't understand much of it.

It would be really helpful if anyone of the experienced veterans explain the steps to get this conversion from HTTP ot JMS (in simple english which you guys do best) so that i could understand and implement it.

Also would like to get any info on checking if the SOAP over JMS is transparent (whether we could monitor the request & response).

Thanks in advance and cheers!!

Comment: @skaffman fortunately or unfortunately yes...

Comment: You should also mention what container you are using (e.g., Jetty, Tomcat) as transport-layer stuff interacts with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Internet can provide plenty of examples. Here is something to start:
[SOAP over JMS by CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/soap-over-jms-10-support.html) and [Advanced CXF configuration for JMS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JMS+Transport)

The move from WS inbound call to JMS inbound message is quite transparent.

Simple high-level steps (in simple English to start with):

(a) Setup your JMS server
make sure it works by testing it - send messages to it using OpenJMS, Hermes, or some other client.

(b) In the CXF setup the connection to the JMS server and specific Queue

(c) Inbound messages: in your code, create an MDB (MessageDrivenBean) class, which is linked to the CXF connection setup

(d) Outboud messages: in your code, define a controller which uses the Context of CXF to get the connection and session to the JMS - and can send a message using them.

I'll be happy to hear how it goes.

Comment: and that failed i guess, need to do that in spring boot, any help?

Comment: you posted link is not working, can you please give any alternative links to resolve the same issue